# sqlcmd sqlcmdheaders - turn headers back on - 0 wont work, large number needed instead

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlcmd

Using sqlcmd on sql server 2005.  Wondering if later versions have this minor issue?

```
SQLCMDHEADERS = "0"
1> select "test" as test
2> go
test
----
test
1> :setvar sqlcmdheaders -1
2> go
1> select "test" as test
2> go
test
1> :setvar sqlcmdheaders 0
Sqlcmd: Error: The scripting variable 'sqlcmdheaders', set with the setvar command, has an invalid value: '0'.
```

Yet 0 is the default value.

Have tried various ideas like using "0" instead of just 0.  The solution seems to be just to use a large number.  Note that other sqlcmd variables can be set to 0 (ie sqlcmdmaxvartypewidth).

Using 'blank' gives no error and no change.

```
SQLCMDHEADERS = "0"
1> :setvar sqlcmdheaders
2> go
1> :listvar
SQLCMDHEADERS = "0"
```

Comment: So basically I am asking: 1) Is this a bug?  2) Is this fixed in sql server 2008?  3) Is a large number (eg 10000) the best work around?

Comment: Dejavu!  Hi me and still and issue.  This is definitely a bug.  We want to be able to return to sqlcmd initial state of one set of header lines per query execution.  Currently have access to both 2008 and 2012 server and still an issue.   Back to resets of a large number or fire up a new sqlcmd session.